# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just moved a bunch of javascript from being inline, into a separate js file, to take advantage of caching files etc.

When I load my page that consumes the js file, I get the following error message:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /

The line number it's complaining about looks like this:

```
url:'<?php echo site_url('switches/showknownvins/'.$Name.'/'.$model.'/'.$fn);?>',
```

It's a part of an ajax call.  The lines of code above and below look like this:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:'<?php echo site_url('switches/showknownvins/'.$Name.'/'.$model.'/'.$fn);?>',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(returnDataFromController) {
```

I have a total of 203 lines of js code, starting with :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

and ending with

```
 });
```

When I paste the code back into the PHP file, it works fine.
I can't see where my error is.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

If I rename my .js file to .php and include that, what's the impact?  Will the web server still cache it ?  That's really what I'm after. I'm trying to improve the speed of my web application because I have a lot of mobile users.

Comment: You're trying to do PHP stuff in your JavaScript file.

Comment: php isn't interpreted in .js files.

Comment: Did you set up your web server to parse JS files with PHP before sending them to the web browser?

Comment: Looks like CodeIgniter. Are you using CodeIgniter to serve the JS files through a PHP controller?

Comment: @Pointy This *is* PHP code, op needs to show the generated HTML.

Comment: Please show us the *generated JavaScript*, not the server side code that generates it.

Comment: @Madbreaks That's his problem -- since it's not being processed by PHP, the generated JS is the PHP source.

Comment: @Madbreaks, do you mean you want me to re-include the contents of my .js file as inline js inside my php... render the page... and then post the results?

Comment: It sounds like you took JavaScript code, portions of which are generated by PHP, and copied it into a `.js` file.  That, of course, will not work.  Anything PHP-related has to be in a PHP file (which is probably why it was inline in the first place).  Look at the value of your `url:` -- it's set to the result of a PHP function called `site_url`.

Comment: @Madbreaks, yes you're right.  I was doing this for a bunch of different php files... and didn't look closely at this particular file before moving all the js to a separate file.  But it *sounds* like I can accomplish the same thing by just renaming to .php?  I want to know what the pros /cons are... Sounds like you don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, yes using CI to create a view.  The view is then including .js file.  ? can you explain why that's relevant?

Comment: I think you need to get a good grip on what is client-side vs. server-side. So here's how it works: web browser (client) requests URL with `.php` -> Apache responds -> extension is `.php` so Apache calls upon PHP to parse the file -> Apache sends parsed file (all HTML) -> client gets file and sees external JS link -> another request is initiated to Apache -> Apache sees `.js` extension -> Apache says `well that should be plain text, no need for a parser, send to client as is` -> client receives JS file with foreign PHP tags in it -> FUBAR!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, that part, I understand.  I didn't understand your question about Codeigniter.

Comment: Oh sorry for that long explanation then. I will provide an answer because this comment box does not have enough room =) and I'll delete it later to avoid downvotes due to my non-related answer to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript was inline because portions of it (notably here, the `url` value for the JavaScript AJAX call) was being set by PHP before being returned to the client.  Hopefully you can see this from the paste of the problematic line in your question.

Of course, when that PHP code gets to the user's browser, the browser won't understand it -- it's PHP code.  Either keep the code you had inline as it was, or do the much harder thing and set up your server to serve dynamic JS if/when a requested static JS file isn't found.

Comment: thanks.  Somehow I missed that obvious problem.  In this case, I will try to save the url as a hidden string in the HTML... and then have this js look up the url from the DOM element.  But I never knew you could serve dynamic JS ... so I've learned something new.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

By default, filenames ending in `.js` are not run through the PHP processor.

You can either reconfigure your webserver to do this. Or rename your `.js` file to have a `.php` suffix.

Renaming it to `.php` should not affect caching, but you can send cache control headers to try to help the browser out.

Comment: That's my point. If he wants to generate JS from a PHP file, he has to tell the server to run it through PHP.

Comment: Read the first line of his question: he's moving his JS from the HTML file that was generated from PHP into a separate file of its own.

Comment: Changing the js file to not rely on embedded php logic would be a better idea, renaming the file to x.php will mean its not served with the right mimetype, and ..fail as it won't have the function `site_url`.

Comment: If you care about the mimetype, add `header("text/javascript");`. But most browsers won't care.

Comment: @Barmar please see my Edit 1 in post

Comment: @Barmar, since it's just the one URL variable that I need, I think I will remove the PHP from the logic instead of reconfiguring my web server.  But +1 for sharing your thoughts. I learned something new from my silly mistake!  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

With CodeIgniter you can serve JS through a controller like this:

### Create a resources controller:

`/codeigniter/2.1.4/yourAppName/controllers/resources.php`

**In `resources.php` put this:**

```
class Resources extends CI_Controller
{
    public function js()
    {
        // JS call should look like the code below in your HTML
        // <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jsFileName.js"></script>
        // $this->uri->uri_string() should give the string "resources/js/jsFileName.js"
        if(is_file(APPPATH.'views/'.$this->uri->uri_string()))
        {
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Cache-Control: maxage=604800"); // 1 week
            header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', (time()+604800)).' GMT'); // expire in 1 week
            header('Content-type: text/javascript');

            $this->load->view($this->uri->uri_string());
        }
    }
}
```

### Create a JS view

`/codeigniter/2.1.4/yourAppName/views/resources/js/jsFileName.js`

**In `jsFileName.js` you can now use the full CodeIgniter library and native PHP:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo site_url('switches/showknownvins/'.$Name.'/'.$model.'/'.$fn);?>',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(returnDataFromController){
        }
    });
});
```

It is worth noting that any autoloading that you declared in `/config/autoload.php` will be autoloaded upon every single JS call so depending on how heavy your APP is I would recommend forking a CI_Controller that only loads the bare necessities. **Also if you are doing session stuff upon calling a JS file then things get REALLY ugly and unstable.**

Comment: +1 for showing me this.  DIdn't know you could do this.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you like it! You can also do CSS with the same logic by creating a `css()` function in the same controller and using `header('Content-type: text/css');`

Comment: I like it because you can set date for expiration!

Comment: well, i've implemented the solution / bug fix that Madbreaks and i discussed.  so i can't make it the answer with a good conscience!  But i will post another question specifically re: how to do this in CI and you can paste your answer in there, and remove it from here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46966/discussion-between-dot-and-monkeyzeus)

Comment: No prob about the accepted answer. Anyways, I am now leaving work so I can check the chat room in about 2 hours if you want